# interface and inheritance: "return type int is not compatible"

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

```
public interface MyInterface{
    public int myMethod();
}


public class SuperClass {
    public String myMethod(){
        return "Super Class";
    }
}

public class DerivedClass extends SuperClass implements MyInterface {
    public String myMethod() {...}  // this line doesn't compile 
    public int myMethod() {...}     // this is also unable to compile
}
```

When I try to compile `DerivedClass` it gives me the error

```
java: myMethod() in interfaceRnD.DerivedClass cannot override myMethod() in interfaceRnD.SuperClass
  return type int is not compatible with java.lang.String
```

How should I solve this issue?

Comment: now it sounds interesting

Comment: So is there actually something wrong with `public String myMethod() {...}` ? From my understanding, the only issue is the line just after. Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The error results from the fact that a call to `myMethod` will be ambiguous - which of the two methods should be called? From [JLS §8.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2):

> **It is a compile-time error to declare two methods with override-equivalent signatures in a class.**

The return type of a method is not a part of its signature, so you are receiving an error in accordance with the statement above.

Assuming you can't simply rename the conflicting methods, you can't use inheritance in this case, and will need to use an alternative like [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition):

```
class DerivedClass implements MyInterface {

    private SuperClass sc;

    public String myMethod1() {
        return sc.myMethod();
    }

    public int myMethod() {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: i got you arshajii ...thanks a lot for solution.. i should prefer composition .... thanks a lot agian...

Answer (score 13):

You can't have two methods with the same signature but different return types.

This is because the compiler cannot know which method you are trying to invoke when you do `object.myMethod();`.

Answer (score 2):

Method overloading is differentiated by their parameter. Here `myMethod()` in both interface and superclass has similar parameter signature. So you can not do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have 2 methods with the same signature but with distinct return types. If it could be it can't be determinated wich method was invoked.

BTW all methods in interface are `public` and `abstract`.

```
public interface MyInterface{
 int myMethod();
}
```

What you can do is have an interface with input parameter, this is called `overloading`

example:

```
        public interface MyInterface{
         String myMethod(String param);
        }
        and in your class

        public class DerivedClass extends SuperClass implements MyInterface{


        public String myMethod(){ ...}  
        public String myMethod(String param) {...}   
       }
```